# Find all possible Sequences creation in a tree using Scala macros

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I want to find all possible Sequences creation in a tree, using Scala macros.

```
val l = List(1, 2)
val v = Vector(1, 2)
val ab = ArrayBuffer(1, 2)
val s = Seq(1, 2)
```

but the following match doesn't work:

```
case Apply(TypeApply(Select(path, Name("apply")), _), args) if path.tpe <:< weakTypeOf[SeqFactory[Any]] => ...
```

Similarly, I need to find all accesses by index on a sequence:

```
val v = Vector(1, 2)
val one = v(0)
```

or all 'apply' method calls on a path, which path.tpe <:< ????[Seq[_]

How to write this check?
This doesn't compile:

```
case Apply(Select(path, Name("apply")), List(idx)) if path.tpe <:< typeOf[Seq[_]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you've tried, but at a glance it looks like you're missing at least two pieces: you need to use a [`Traverser`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#traversal_via_) to traverse all descendants of a tree, and you need to typecheck each candidate tree to make sure it gets desugared to the point that you can tell that you've got an application of a `SeqFactory`.

For example, here's a quick implementation that prints all of the sequence creation trees in a class at compile time:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object SeqSearch {
  def printCreatesInClass = macro printCreatesInClass_impl

  def printCreatesInClass_impl(c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._
    import scala.collection.generic.SeqFactory

    val factorySym = c.typeOf[SeqFactory[Seq]].typeSymbol

    def isCreation(tree: Tree) = c.typeCheck(tree) match {
      case Apply(TypeApply(Select(factory, name), _), _) if
        factory.tpe.baseClasses.contains(factorySym) &&
        name == newTermName("apply") => true
      case _ => false
    }

    object printCreates extends Traverser {
      override def traverse(tree: Tree) = tree match {
        case application @ Apply(_, args) if isCreation(application) =>
          println("Matched create: " + application)
          super.traverseTrees(args)
        case _ => super.traverse(tree)
      }
    }

    printCreates(c.enclosingClass)

    c.literalUnit
  }
}
```

It works like this:

```
scala> class Foo {
     |   SeqSearch.printCreatesInClass
     |   val l = List(1, 2)
     |   val v = Vector(1, 2)
     |   val ab = collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(1, 2)
     |   val s = Seq(1, 2)
     | }
Matched create: List(1, 2)
Matched create: Vector(1, 2)
Matched create: collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(1, 2)
Matched create: Seq(1, 2)
defined class Foo
```

Finding accesses is similar—just add the following methods to the object above:

```
  def printAccessesInClass = macro printAccessesInClass_impl

  def printAccessesInClass_impl(c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._

    def isAccess(tree: Tree) = c.typeCheck(tree) match {
      case Apply(Select(seq, name), _) if
        seq.tpe <:< typeOf[Seq[Any]] &&
        name == newTermName("apply") => true
      case _ => false
    }

    object printAccesses extends Traverser {
      override def traverse(tree: Tree) = tree match {
        case application @ Apply(_, args) if isAccess(application) =>
          println("Matched access: " + application)
          super.traverseTrees(args)
        case _ => super.traverse(tree)
      }
    }

    printAccesses(c.enclosingClass)

    c.literalUnit
  }
```

And then:

```
scala> class Foo {
     |   SeqSearch.printCreatesInClass
     |   SeqSearch.printAccessesInClass
     |   val xs = List(1, 2, 3)
     |   val xh = xs(0)
     | }
Matched create: List(1, 2, 3)
Matched access: xs(0)
defined class Foo
```

It should be pretty easy to adjust the side effects of the `Traverser` to capture whatever information you're interested in instead of just printing the trees at compile time.

Comment: Thank you, Travis, your answer really helped. One more question, though. Could you give an example when one would need to c.typeCheck(factory).tpe.baseClasses.contains(factorySym). Asking because I've got factory.tpe.baseClasses.contains(factorySym) working fine.

Comment: Ah, right. There's no need to typecheck twice—the one outside the match will do. I've edited the answer, thanks.